# Financial Services Cloud with Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx, financial-services-cloud

I was wondering if anyone was able to use SFDX with Financial Services Cloud (FSC)?  I am currently working on a FSC implementation, but since FSC is like a managed package, the scratch org doesn't have those objects by default.  Or is Force.com Migration Tool the only option for now?  Any info or links will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to use the ADK that salesforce ISV team provides for fsc.You can access the open source project [here](https://github.com/sfdx-isv/fsc-demo-pack)

The best part about ADK is it also has templates that gives you test data for your org.

The other alternative is since FSC publishes package [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323341&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), you can use the `sfdx force:package:install --package=<packageIdofFSC>` command with the packageIds .

Comment: You can also install it by pushing the xml metadata file (`force-app -> main -> default -> installedPackages -> FinServ.installedPackage-meta.xml`) upon creating a scratch org with the `"FinancialServicesUser"` feature.

Comment: Can we install fsc directly to any develop org?, If i try install fsc package to any develop org we get error of claim__C and InsurancePolicy__c Object missing error. I know we can avoid this error in scratch org, what about developer org ?

Answer (score 3):

To install the FSC Managed Package into a Scratch Org (see other answers or the "[Product Specific Terms section of your order form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud.meta/financial_services_cloud/fsc_admin_install_managed_package.htm)" for install instructions), you will need to enable the scratch org features `ContactsToMultipleAccounts` (you will get an error explaining that it is missing if you don't) and `FinancialServicesUser:x`, [where `x` is a number between 1 and 10](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm?search_text=FinancialServicesUser) (you will get errors about a missing `Claim` object if you don't).  FSC supports Person Accounts; if you wish you use them you should add the `PersonAccounts` feature as well.  Here's a basic `project-scratch-def.json`:

```
{
  "orgName": "FSC Scratch Org",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": ["PersonAccounts","ContactsToMultipleAccounts", "FinancialServicesUser:5"]
}
```

Comment: Can we install fsc directly to any develop org?, If i try install fsc package to any develop org we get error of claim__C and InsurancePolicy__c Object missing error. I know we can avoid this error in scratch org, what about developer org ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install FSC in a Scratch Org, just as you would in production or a Sandbox, either by the URL or with [force:package:install](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm) (also [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_install_pkg_cli.htm)) from the Salesforce DX CLI. If using unlocked packages, you can also specify dependencies on FSC in your unlocked package to allow the package versions to be created.

Comment: Can we install fsc directly to any develop org?, If i try install fsc package to any develop org we get error of claim__C and InsurancePolicy__c Object missing error. I know we can avoid this error in scratch org, what about developer org ?

Comment: @NITHESHK Creating a new Developer Edition, it should already be enabled. For orgs older than Winter '20, you'd have to contact Support to get it enabled. For example, my old 2007 Developer Edition account doesn't have this feature enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Finally In winter 20 is launched as a feature. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm